# Pass by ref not working on convesion from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, pass-by-reference

I am trying to work out some code from a previous developer that was written in Vb.Net whereby he has created the following method which passes a string method ByRef as shown here:

```
Function prefixZeros(ByRef numberString As String, ByVal stringLength As Integer) As String

    While numberString.Length < stringLength
        numberString = "0" & numberString
    End While

    Return numberString

End Function
```

He subsequently calls it as follows:

```
Dim RandomClass As New Random()
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 99999999)
Dim RandomString As String = prefixZeros(RandomNumber, 8)
```

and

```
Dim terminalId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("terminalId").ToString()
terminalId = prefixZeros(terminalId, 8)
```

or

```
prefixZeros(DateTime.Now.Month, 2)
```

I am trying to replicate this code in C# but I have been unable to do thus far, on converting the prefixZeros method over I have the following:

```
public string prefixZeros(ref string numberString, int stringLength)
{
  while (numberString.Length < stringLength)
  {
    numberString = "0" + numberString;
  }
  return numberString;
}
```

But If I attempt to call in it a similar fashion as:

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
int RandomNumber = 0;
RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(0, 999999999);
string RandomString = prefixZeros(RandomNumber, 9);
```

or

```
string terminalId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["terminalId"].ToString();
terminalId = prefixZeros(terminalId, 8);
```

or

```
prefixZeros(DateTime.Now.Month, 2)
```

I am getting errors that there are some arguments which I can see is the types but I am not sure what I am supposed to be doing at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you using pass by reference at all? You're returning the value anyway... (There are much more efficient ways of doing this, too... and I suspect this isn't doing what is intended anyway...) Also note that you're trying to pass in an integer, when the parameter is a string... and you're not specifying `ref` at the call site. You'd see compile-time errors with option strict on in VB, too, I believe.

Comment: like I said this was someone elses code I am struggling to even understand what he was attempting to do to be honest

Comment: None of this makes sense, unless you use Visual Basic.  Which is very permissive when you do illogical things, it is a "friendly" language that does what you say instead of telling you that you probably shouldn't do it.  C# is not a language like that.  Using *ref* does not make sense when the method doesn't change the object reference.  Passing an *int* to a method that expects a *string* does not make sense.  You'll have to write the sensible version, C# insists.  If you don't like that kind of insistence then do stay on VB.NET.  And compile with Option Strict On for a while to get the sense

Comment: I do not mind that kind of insistence in fact I insist on it I was just struggling to see what he was doing here and I thought I was missing something

Comment: the VB function just add a left padding. For example 00abc = prefixZeros("abc",5). You can easily write code in C# to achieve this task

Comment: Code smell and VB seem to coexist quite frequently. There's been a lot of instances of me looking through something written in VB that makes me go WTF. Then I realize the language begets (and almost encourages) bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, to pass a parameter as ref, you have to specify that at the call site as well as the method definition:

```
string RandomString = prefixZeros(ref RandomNumber, 9);
```

except... you can't do that because `RandomNumber` is an `int` and the function is expecting a string. Normally, in C# you might handle the type conversion like this:

```
string RandomString = prefixZeros(RandomNumber.ToString(), 9);
```

except that doesn't work with `ref`, because the result of `ToString` is just a temporary value! I'm guessing the VB code you're looking at does not have `Option Strict On`. Without that VB will automatically convert the number into a temporary string, and VB has no problem sending a temporary string into a `ByRef` parameter. On the other hand, C# will not allow a temporary value to be passed into a `ref` parameter. So you could do this:

```
string numberAsString = RandomNumber.ToString();
string RandomString = prefixZeros(ref numberAsString, 9);
```

and that will work for your method call.

Since your function returns the value that it's modifying, it doesn't really make sense to pass the parameter as `ref` anyway. This a common sort of sloppy coding that is allowed in VB but C# will be more strict about. And you don't want to be calling `ToString` everywhere, since it probably only makes sense to prefix zeroes to a number. So you should consider changing the function declaration to:

```
public string prefixZeros(int number, int stringLength)
```

But if you're converting a large code base from VB to C# you will want to check for calls that ignore the return value because they expect the parameter to be modified.

Comment: Thanks Erik I actually had thought it was something so simple as this but I was so long looking at this code then I think i fell into one of its many holes and became temporarily blinded :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string RandomString = RandomClass.Next(0, 999999999).toString().PadLeft(9, '0');
```

Comment: Hi Frenchi thank you for the input but I think that the explanation and solution offered by Erik clears up the confusion for the next developer after me :)